# Rest API Spring. Code 403 at authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

Faced difficulty setting up authorization in Spring. Created two Rest-controllers: for authorization and for uploading/downloading images. I make requests to the API through Postman, authorization occurs, but when I try to interact with the image controller, I always get a 403 code. I tried to hang **disable()** on **csrf** and **cors** - it does not help.

I will be grateful for any help!

Set up the security configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Autowired
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http.
                    authorizeHttpRequests().
                    requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().
                    requestMatchers("/api/image/**").authenticated().
                    and().
                    csrf().disable().
                    build();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
            return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
        }
```

Authorization controller:

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/auth")
    public class AuthController {
    
        @Autowired
        private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
        @PostMapping("/sign-up")
        public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody AuthDTO authDTO){
            if(userService.checkByUsername(authDTO.getUsername()))
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(authDTO.getUsername());
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(authDTO.getPassword()));
    
            Role role = roleRepository.findByRoleName(RoleName.ROLE_USER).get();
            user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(role));
    
            userService.addUser(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        }
    
    
        @PostMapping("/sign-in")
        public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody AuthDTO authDTO){
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authDTO.getUsername(),authDTO.getPassword()));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    
            User user = userService.getByUsername(authentication.getName());
    
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user.getId());
        }
    }
```

Image Controller:

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/image")
    public class ImageController {
    
        @Autowired
        private ImageService imageService;
    
        @PostMapping("/upload")
        public ResponseEntity<Long> uploadImage(@RequestParam("image")MultipartFile imageFile){
            try{
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(imageService.saveImage(imageFile));
            }catch (Exception e){
                return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
            }
        }
    
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/download/{id}",
        produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody byte[] downloadImage(@PathVariable  Long id){
            return imageService.getImageById(id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mention which authentication type you are using, if you are choosing basic auth from Postman authorization to enter username and password then in Spring Security configuration you have to mention `httpBasic` same as follow:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws  Exception {
    return http
               .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/image/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .build();
}
```